# How to convert string with double backslashes to single backslahses

Tags: c++, arrays, string, byte

How do I convert the following string:

```
std::string s = "\\xfc\\xe8\\x82"
```

to the char array equivalent:

```
char s[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82"
```

Comment: Just to be sure, are you aware that `"\x00\x00\x00"` is a char array of 3 zeros followed by the terminating null?

Comment: So the question to you is this -- how did the original string get to be formatted in a way that is "not good".  I think we're missing some details.  What program stuck bogus slash characters onto the original string?  If that is how the original string looks, then you need to fix the program giving you the string in that fashion.  Or are you misinterpreting how strings and escape characters work in C++ source code?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a general misunderstanding with escape characters in string literals.

The literal `"\\xfc\\xe8\\x82"` as a string uses "\" as an escape character.  "\" will be reduced to "\". As you would expect. So, if you print your given `std::string`, then the result will be:
`\xfc\xe8\x82`.

So, what you want to do now is: Create a char array containing those hex values, given in the original `std::string`.

Please note: Your statement `char s[] = "\xfc\xe8\x82";` will create a C-Style array of char, with the size 4 and containing:

```
s[0]=fc, s[1]=e8, s[2]=82, s[3]=0
```

In the example below I show 2 proposals for conversion. 
 1. Straight forward conversion
 2. Using C++ standard algorithms

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


// Hex digit String
std::regex hexValue{R"(\\[xX]([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))"};


int main ()
{   
    // Source string
    std::string s1 = "\\xfc\\xe8\\x82";
    std::cout << "s 1: " << s1 << "\n";


    // Proposal 1 ------------------------------------------------------

    // Target array
    unsigned char s2[3];

    // Convert bytes from strings
    for (int i=0; i<s1.size()/4; ++i ) {

        // Do conversion. Isolate substring, the convert
        s2[i] = std::strtoul(s1.substr(i*4+2,2).c_str(), nullptr,16);
        // Result is now in s2

        // Output value as tring and decimal value
        std::cout << s1.substr(i*4+2,2) << " -> " << std::hex << static_cast <unsigned short>(s2[i]) 
                  << " -> " << std::dec << static_cast <unsigned short>(s2[i]) << "\n";
    }

    // Proposal 2 ------------------------------------------------------

    // Get the tokens
    std::vector<std::string> vstr(std::sregex_token_iterator(s1.begin(),s1.end(),hexValue, 1), {});

    // Convert to unsigned int
    std::vector<unsigned int> vals{};

    std::transform(vstr.begin(), vstr.end(), std::back_inserter(vals), 
        [](std::string &s){ return static_cast<unsigned>(std::strtoul(s.c_str(), nullptr,16)); } );

    std::copy(vals.begin(), vals.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

The second solution will eat any number of hex numbers given in a string